# Electrical energy saving

Tags: voltage, energy, voltage-source, terminal, outlet

[image]

"You can not pay for the light! This CUTE for years was..."

I wonder, what will happen if to do what is illustrated on the picture.
I think there are two cases:

1. Hot terminal of left outlet connect to the hot terminal of right outlet, and zero as well.
2. Hot terminal of left outlet connect to the 0 terminal of right outlet, and 0 terminal of left outlet connect to the hot terminal of right outlet.

What will happen in these 2 cases? How much money will I save(approximately, +, -)?

Comment: You should never make a cable that is mains plug to mains plug because as soon as you plug one end into a live socket, you have exposed live mains pins at the other end that are a hazard. Such cable assemblies violate electrical wiring codes/standards/regulations/laws which are there for your safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you **honestly** think that this would work?

**If** that would work then why isn't everyone using this and enjoying free electricity?

For case 1: **nothing** will happen as you made a connection that is already there, this is how the outlet is wired inside.

For case 2: you made a **short**, as soon as you plugin the 2nd plug into the socket there will be **a large bang** very likely **a large spark** and possibly **some smoke will appear**. Then hopefully the fuse in your fusebox will blow to protect your house from burning down.

You will **not** save any money, in fact you ruined two power leads.

These kind of messages are only believed by those who are [gullible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gullible). Don't be one of those people.

Comment: "Do you honestly think that this would work?", eys suer, wy not?

Comment: I'm an EE so I kinda know some stuff about electricity. Sure, that is no proof. To prove it you could try the same thing with a battery (more safe than experimenting with mains power), just connect it to itself and let it power a bicycle light bulb for example. Does the battery last longer or even forever? You can also prove me wrong by showing proper **proof** that this scheme does work. My bet: you can't because it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

if those three outlets are on the same phase you won't save any money. if they aren't you'll test the fuses on the circuits involved.

Either way nothing good will happen.

Comment: If the fuses blow, you get disconnected from the network and cannot consume power anymore.

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr That sure does save power.

Comment: Maybe I should make an answer from it, but sometimes ppl. aren't that funny around ee.se